# How do I make the Windows Phone volume switch target Media + Apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can my Windows Phone 8 app make the hardware volume switch target Media + Apps instead of Ringer + Notifications without media being played at the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app has the `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK` capability specified in the manifest, the volume ringer should show Media by default. You don't have to actually be playing media at the time.

Comment: Thank you very much, that does do the trick. Unfortunately it means the app has to ask for a new permission "media playback" which it doesn't otherwise need. I don't suppose you know of an alternative method?

Comment: There's no other way for 8.0 apps (8.1 Universal apps get it by default). But a lot of apps in the store have it and there are no privacy concerns so it shouldn't be a concern for anyone.